# Render returns nothing when using promise

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, render

I'm trying to implement my render function so that it waits until I finish either scraping data from the web (if AsyncStorage doesn't have it) or fetching it from AsyncStorage, but I'm struggling with the promise aspect of it:

```
render() {
    let pic = {
        uri: 'https://i.imgur.com/G19Jnuj.jpg'
    };
    this.renderAttributes()
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("finished val: " + this.state.name);
            console.log("finished response: " + response);
            return (
                <View style={shared.basicView}>
                    <Image source={pic} style ={styles.circleImage}/>
                    <Text style={styles.infoText}>{this.state.name}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}>Bio</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.infoText}>blah blah</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}>Email</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.infoText}>blah blah</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}
                          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Repositories')}>
                        Public Repos Count</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.infoText}>3</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}
                          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Followers')}>
                        Follower Count</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.infoText}>0</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}
                          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Following')}>
                        Following Count</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.infoText}>0</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.titleText}>Profile Created</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.infoText}>November 2015</Text>
                </View>
            )
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Profile creation failed: " + error);
            return(null);
        })
}
```

The rest of the class and the renderAttributes function are defined like so:

```
class ProfileScreen extends Component {
    state: any;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            bio: '',
            email: '',
            repoCount: '',
            followerCount: '',
            followingCount: '',
            profileCreated: ''
        };
        this.renderAttributes = this.renderAttributes.bind(this);
    }

    async renderAttributes() {
        console.log("inside ga");
        let jsonData=null;
        try {
            axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/dummy')
                .then(async (response) => {
                    console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
                    jsonData=response;
                    console.log("jsonData: " + JSON.stringify(jsonData));

                    const nameVal = await AsyncStorage.getItem('name');
                    if(nameVal !== null) {
                        console.log("name val: " + nameVal);
                        this.setState({name: nameVal});
                    }
                    else {
                        try {
                            await AsyncStorage.setItem('name', jsonData.data.name);
                        }
                        catch (error) {
                            console.log("Set name error: " + error);
                        }

                        if(jsonData.data.name == null) {
                            this.setState({name: 'n/a'});
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("name: " + jsonData.data.name);
                            this.setState({name: jsonData.data.name});
                        }
                    }

                    const bio = await AsyncStorage.getItem('bio');
                    if(bio !== null) {
                        this.setState({bio: bio});
                    }
                    else {
                        try {
                            await AsyncStorage.setItem('bio', jsonData.data.bio);
                        }
                        catch (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                        if(jsonData.data.bio == null) {
                            this.setState({bio: 'n/a'});
                        }
                        else {
                            this.setState({bio: jsonData.data.bio});
                        }
                    }
                    // etc for each attribute in state
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error fetching: ' + error);
                });

        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log('Error creating attributes: ' + error);
        }
    }
```

(Excuse all my console.log statements). To me, it seems like this should either return null or return a View no matter what, but I keep getting the error `"Invariant Violation: ProfileScreen(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."`. None of my catch statements are triggered. I'm honestly baffled; there's two things I've noticed though that may be the culprit: 1. my IDE highlights this.state.name as being an unresolved variable name, 2. I did not explicitly define a promise inside of `renderAttributes` (should I have to?). Also, based solely on print statements, it seems like things inside `this.renderAttributes().then(response)` print before `axios.get.then()`; not sure if that's a red herring though. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not a react user, but from the last time I played with it `render` was not an `async` operation, to handle `async` you would alter the `state`, this would then cause a `render` method, and it's from the state you would update the view.

Comment: @Keith hmm, I guess that's what I thought I was doing. This is definitely a rookie question, but why does it matter that render is not asynchronous? If I force it to wait for `renderAttributes()`, shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: `I guess that's what I thought I was doing`, as soon as you use Promises, async / await / callbacks etc, your using async..   ps. when you `await` something it doesn't make it into a `sync` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to resolve a promise inside the render() function, and the promise itself is asynchronous, and you're not returning anything so implicitly will return undefined.

The render function should be pure without any side effects.

you should put the async logic to fetch your data inside one of the react lifecycle hook, like `componentWillMount()` or `componentDidMount()`

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Ok, I read the docs, and I want to make sure I understand correctly; I should take the call to `renderAttributes` out of `render` and purely return the view with `this.state.<attributeName>` as the values of my elements. Then, in `componentDidMount`, I should call `renderAttributes`, which will trigger a 'revaluation' of render with updated state values?

Comment: exactly the "unpure" logic contained in your renderAttributes() should be put in one of the lifecycle hook like componentDidMount(), when the promise is resolved you set the state and this will trigger a rerender.

Comment: edit: looks like calling `componentWillMount` would be a better idea, actually

Comment: here there is a nice comparison between the two: https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the best place [as stated by docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), is **componentDidMount**

You should provide a 'loading screen' at the first run (like empty fields and/or spinner) and when data is retrieved (all done in componentDidMount) and state set, show it

**componentWillMount**:

> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.
>   For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.

**componentDidMount**:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request.